# Why does the donut texture not show?

Tags: texturing

I was following the legendary donut tutorial and rendered an animation. I noticed that the donut texture deformed in a weird way and cant figure what caused it or how to fix it. Help?[image: Notice how the donut itself is transparent while its texture is deformed]

Comment: hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Did you leave it to finish rendering? - The top-left stats show "Sample 23/1024" which means that it hadn't finished rendering when you saved that image.